# Create and rename .h-file

Tags: rename

My problem is more that I have managed to create a -h-file but I want to give another name than the default name which is something like "newh". Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe I should add that the environment that I use is AtmelStudio 6.1.

Answer (score -1):

no there's no way H is H and that's how's it's going to bee u try to change it   you'll go crazy trying its legendary GOD never dies **H***never*[http://www.hsecurity.com

> $ echo "hello^H^H"
>   hello
>      ^
>      `-- cursor position
>   $ echo "hello^H^H "
>   hel o
>       ^`
>   -- cursor position

][1](http://hsecurity.com/H)